# Need assistance with Swift: open / replace view controller based on incoming URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, firebase-dynamic-links

We had an app developed for us but are wanting to expand its functionality. The app has a few features but for this context it is a property app similar to Zoopla for example.

It uses firebase for its database where there is a 'Homes' collection, with each home being a document with an 'id' field which is also the name of the document. I have configured the app to create dynamic links allowing users to share properties.

```
@objc private func shareButtonTapped() {
  var components = URLComponents()
  components.scheme = "https"
  components.host = "letmeapp.page.link"
  components.path = "/homes"
  
  let homeIDQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "HomeID", value: viewModel.home.id)
  print(viewModel.home.id)
  components.queryItems = [homeIDQueryItem]
  let home = viewModel.home
  guard let linkParameter = components.url else { return }
  print("I am sharing \(linkParameter.absoluteString)")
  
  guard let shareLink = DynamicLinkComponents.init(link: linkParameter, domainURIPrefix: "https://letmeapp.page.link")
  else {
      print("Couldn't create FDL components")
      return
  }
```

The app has various view controllers, i want to open the 'HomeInfoViewController' when the user follows the share link, and display the property that has been shared. I don't yet have enough experience with Swift and despite all of my efforts i cant wrap my head around how to do this..

In AppDelegate, this code parses the incoming URL to get the ID from the URL:

```
    if components.path == "/homes" {
    if let homeIdQueryItem = queryItems.first(where: {$0.name == "homeID"}) {
        guard let homeID = homeIdQueryItem.value else { return }
```

Below is an example of (i think) where the app opens an instance of the HomeInfoViewController when a home is selected from the list of homes in the HomeListViewController:

```
  private func openHomeInfoViewController(for home: HomeModel) {
   let homeInfoViewModel = HomeInfoViewModel(home: home)
   let homeInfoViewController = HomeInfoViewController(viewModel: homeInfoViewModel)
   navigationController?.pushViewController(homeInfoViewController, animated: true)}


    extension HomeListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       let cellModel = viewModel.cellModels[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]    
       if let cellModel = cellModel as? HomeListResultTableViewCellModel {
        openHomeInfoViewController(for: cellModel.home)
        }
       }
     }
```

This is another example of where the HomeInfoViewController is pushed when the user selects a property from their list of 'saved properties'.

```
  private func openHomeInfoViewController(for home: HomeModel) {
    let homeInfoViewModel = HomeInfoViewModel(home: home)
    let homeInfoViewController = HomeInfoViewController(viewModel: homeInfoViewModel)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(homeInfoViewController, animated: true)
  }
```

I think my main issue is i'm not understanding how the program knows which home has been pressed, hopefully its obvious to somebody else :)

I apologise if this is vague, i have tried to provide some context but i can provide more if necessary. Thankyou in advance for any and all contributions.

Charlie

Comment: From the information you provided I think your HomeModel is selected from the homeID,  query item passed in the URL. With that model creating a ViewModel(HomeInfoViewModel) and create the controller(HomeInfoViewController).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your question.  It seems like you're asking "How does the system know what home is associated with the cell that a user taps in the table"  Here's that info.

When the user taps a row in the table view, the system sends the "index path" for that item to `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.  The index path describes the section and row that was tapped.

Your code above calls `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` to remove the highlight from the selected cell.  It then asks the view model to look up the cell record using `viewModel.cellModels[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`.  This is an instance of `HomeListResultTableViewCellModel` and the system determines which home was tapped by looking at the `home` property of that struct.

You probably need to look closer at the `cellModels` object to see how it handles using the indexes to look up a home.

Comment: Thats basically what i'm asking yeah. i figured that was roughly what was happening in that instance but then not how to do the same just based on an already known ID. I am going to have another look today with a fresh head and see if i can figure it with the advice so far, thank you!

Comment: There may not be enough info in the code you've provided to help.  It looks like you want to find out how to build or find a `HomeModel` based on a home's ID.  I'd look right underneath where the `homeIdQueryItem` yields  `homeID` and see what logic follows right after that.